# Can Managed package pass security review when window.postMessage() is used in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, iframe, postmessage

We are working on a managed package that will load a third-party web app inside iFrame in a Lightning web component. To make the thrid party app context-aware we need to send some information from Salesforce to the third-party app.

As of now there are two ways I know to pass down the data from LWC to an iframe.

- As URL parameters
- Using Window.postMessage()

I am pretty sure that the URL parameters have no issues with security review. But don't know about the Window.postMessage(). We need to use this API as there are some event-driven communications involved.

According to MDN doc [Window: postMessage() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
, it is the safe way to achieve this.

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

The `Window.postMessage()` is safe as per this doc as well - [Secure Coding PostMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_postmessage.htm), provided that the below requirements are fulfilled:

> - **While sending messages**
>
>   - Provide a specific destination origin unless there is a need to broadcast your message to all domains
> - **While receiving messages**
>
>   - Setup event listeners only when expecting messages from other windows.
>   - Always check the source origin against a list of allowed origins.
>   - Ensure that the data received is in the expected format. Only interpret the received message as data. Don’t evaluate it as code.
>   - Reply only to trusted origins

Is this sufficient evidence to assume that `window.postMessage()` will not cause any problems in the managed package security review? Has anyone already used this in the managed package?

Comment: Cannot really comment on `postMessage` safety but it provides a mechanism like [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/origin) to make it almost safe. w.r.t. security review I would recommend to checkout [this](https://gist.github.com/jedp/3005816) list. (I have not used it in managed pkg but I guess it needs to be described in false positive doc and it would have same security implications as with its use outside Salesforce.)

Comment: Given that Salesforce has documented "[safe use](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_postmessage.htm)", as you have cited, it would be odd for this to be rejected in a security review. I would, however, recommend that you raise an office hours with the security team or ask this question on the partner enablement forum.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for the link, Thanks Phill.